# How to load image from folder but not resource folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I put my image at /Assets/Test/Textures/Player but without success my code is:

```
IEnumerator loadTexture(string videotype) {

    if(videotype.Equals("3d")) {

        WWW www = new WWW("file:///Assets/Meta1/Textures/Player/3D_foucs.png");
        yield return www;
        texture3D.mainTexture = www.texture;

    } else if(videotype.Equals("2d") ){

    } else if(videotype.Equals("360")) {

    }        
}
```

Comment: Here ([link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LoadingResourcesatRuntime.html)) you can find information about loading resources at runtime.

Comment: Can you explain why not from resources?

Comment: i have put the image to the Texture,and put some of them to the editor,so i donot want to move the image and modify the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your png file in Resources folder of your project and load it using:

```
 Texture2D _texture = Resources.Load("3D_foucs.png") as Texture2D;
```

**EDIT :**

If you really want to avoid using `Resources.Load()` then you can use `Application.dataPath` to access assets folder. But make sure you read [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-dataPath.html) before that.

P.S : [WWW](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) is usually good for loading stuff from outside of project.

E.g from [Application's Persistent Data](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) or from web server.

Hope it helps

Comment: But OP stated that he doesn't want to use resources.

Comment: its not advised to use `www` for loading stuff from within the Assets directory. I have updated the answer anyway.